# spyder (python) variable explorer different view

Tags: python, numpy, spyder

i am looking at a tutorial video, and i copied and paste the code.
somehow the way spyder shows some variables is different from the way in the tutorial video.
this is the way it shows on my pc, i need to double click total_reward to see the value 2178. [image]

and this is the way it is shown in the video
[image]

how can i make spyder show me the value without clicking "class 'numpy.int64'"?
**it is exactly the same code.**

Answer (score 2):

You need to update Spyder, because support for the most important numeric types of Numpy (32 and 64 bits int, float and complex numbers) was added in Spyder **3.1**, released on January/2017.